# Is there a way to stop Listview from reloading on datachange?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I am trying to implement animated removal of items from a listview .then the animation of item going from left to right(off the screen on deletion ) i run an animation on views below it to move up and snap into place but the problem is the list flickers when listview detects the deletion .
my code to run the animation is :

```
 Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.offscreen);
                            itemc.setHasTransientState(true);
                            itemc.startAnimation(an);
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    l.remove(positionc);
                                    adapter.remove(positionc);

                                   // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                                }
                            }, 1050);
                            //animate below views to position



                            ArrayList<View> vl=new ArrayList<View>();
                            //for loop runs and saves all the views below the deleted view 
                            for(int i=position+1;i<=listView.getLastVisiblePosition();i++)
                            {
                                vl.add(listView.getChildAt(i));
                            }
                            //one by one animation is performed on all the views 
                            ListIterator itr=vl.listIterator();
                            while(itr.hasNext())
                            {

                                View v =(View)itr.next();
                                v.setHasTransientState(true);
                                v.animate().setDuration(500).translationYBy(-      itemc.getHeight());//iteam is the view deleted 
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a way of stopping android from running default animation on listview on datasetchange ( wanted to implement my own animation) 
just add :

```
listView.setLayoutTransition(null);
```

this will stop the listview from running its default animation .